# PHP static CLASS __callstatic Magic Method but for variables

Tags: php, static

I have a question.
Having a static class in PHP, that basically holds multiple static classes.
With the function of having a bundled data source and action source but still separated by a clear structure.

Example I would like the following functions to be possible.

For loading a booking for example:

```
$booking_data = SYSTEM::$BOOKING::LOAD(23442);
```

For setting the booking as paid:

```
SYSTEM::$BOOKING::SETPAID(23442);
```

Or for creating a new reseller :

```
SYSTEM::$PARTNER::NEW('John Doe', 'Rambo 1, 2 & 3', 'HisBeautifulPassword1234@!');
```

In this way one can have a very structured way of working in a system.

But for what I know I should define the $BOOKING and $PARTNER first before executing.

However I want to have this done on the fly.
Just like the **__callStatic()** method.

So it should basically ask if a variable is requested, does it exist? And if not does a class exists that has this name. If so then set it.

(not PHP code but explaining my wish)

```
public static function __callStaticVar($name){
    if(method_exists($name) === true){
        self::$name = new $name();
    }
}
```